# Javascript send data to ActionResult that return RedirectToAction

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to send data from javascript to my action that return RedirectToAction and some data.

My Js:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "GetAssetFilterID",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'VidLink' : clipData.src, 'InitialTime': clipData.markIn, 'EndTime': clipData.markOut }),
        dataType: "json",
        /*async: false,*/
    });
```

My Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetAssetFilterID(string VidLink, string InitialTime, string EndTime)
{
    //some code
    return RedirectToAction("Share", new { vid = VidLink, fil = filterName });
}
```

Notes

- I had, on js, the url `controller/action` and the link that it
  generated was `controller/controller/action`.
- I don' get any error on console, nothing happens.
- I don't need to use Ajax, I just want to send data from my Js to my
  ActionResult. Ajax was the sample that I found.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First, you probably don't want to do `JSON.stringify`. jQuery will handle it for you, as needed. Just hand it the object. Second, you don't have a `success` callback or anything. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I don't want to return to javascript. I just wan't that Javascript send data and call the function, and the function return the RedirectToAction, never back to Js @MikeC

Comment: So you want to change pages after you send the data? Then you should submit a form. The whole purpose of AJAX is to allow you to send and retrieve data without changing pages.

Comment: Without the JSON.stringify I get a 500 Internal error. Yes, I just wan't to call the function that sends me to another page. I don't have a form, my function is called by other script @MikeC

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. Do not use ajax if you want to redirect (and if you did want to use ajax for some other reason, remove the `contentType` option and remove `JSON,stringify`)

Comment: I don't need to use Ajax, I just want to send data from my Js to my ActionResult. Ajax was the sample that I found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net mvc4 ajax login: RedirectToAction not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756473/asp-net-mvc4-ajax-login-redirecttoaction-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. All you can do is return a url in the ajax result and use JS to redirect. Return the url in json or similar and in the ajax success or complete callbacks do your redirect.

Because the browser never posted its not expecting a response that would allow/cause a redirect.

Also duplicate of [asp.net mvc4 ajax login: RedirectToAction not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756473/asp-net-mvc4-ajax-login-redirecttoaction-not-working)

Comment: It's strange Javascript don't allow me to send data to a actionresult and without callback

Comment: I don't understand what you mean there.
Without the callback there nothing for javascript to do with any response it gets, RedirectToAction creates a HTTP 302 redirect httpresponse which A) you would have to code manually to handle in the JS B) is ignored by the browser itself since it never made a request (the js did).

Comment: What I want is simple: Js: call and send data to ActionResult. Action result redirect to Share and send some data.

Comment: You cannot return a RedirectToAction result from an AJAX request and get automagically redirected, end of story there. You can POST or GET to the action and it would work or you can do something else in your javascript to handle the response.

Comment: I don't need to use Ajax, I just want to send data from my Js to my ActionResult. Ajax was the sample that I found.

Comment: Just do a normal form POST then using hidden or regular input fields that you can populate with your JS data, it would do what you want then with the redirect to action. I don't know where the data for those fields is coming from but you could throw it into hidden fields or get it from regular user input fields.